# Функция htmlspecialchars и php

Tags: php, mysql, htmlspecialchars

Создал на сайте гостевую, проверяю по разному, все html коды обрабатываются, все замечательно. Но, когда пишу php код:

```
<? echo 'Привет';?>
```

Сообщения не добавляются в базу. Но, ответ идет как сообщение добавлено в базу (Успех).

Добавляю данные в базу так:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['other'])) {

    //Записываю в переменные и htmlspecialchars
    $msg_name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
    $msg_text = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']));
    $msg_other = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['other']));

    //Проверка на пустоту 
    if ($msg_name == "" || $msg_text == "" || $msg_other == "") {
        die("<font color=\"red\">Ошибка</font>");
    } else {

        $db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
        mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Cannot connect to database");
        $query = "INSERT INTO gost(name, message, other, date, time)
VALUES('" . $msg_name . "','" . $msg_text . "','" . $msg_other . "', now(), now())";
        mysql_query($query);
        echo "<font color=\"blue\">Успех</font>";
        mysql_close($db);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Ошибка 404';
}
?>
```

Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: @Maqsood, вы проверяете приход верных данных, но не их добавление в таблицу:

    mysql_query($query);
    echo "<font color=\"blue\">Успех</font>";

вне зависимости от результата `mysql_query()` будет выведено "Успех". Предположу, что запрос не выполняется как минимум из-за присутствия **date** и **time** (не говоря о том, что кавычка в сообщении порушит вообще все) - это не зарезервированные слова (точнее, это зарезервировано-разрешенные слова), но в некоторых запросах их нельзя использовать напрямую. Для точного указания колонок их надо выделять обратными апострофами:

   `date`, `time`

Comment: Спасибо. Я все исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя SQL Injection - очень опасная проблема, от которой ты на 100% не избавишься, если продолжишь пользоваться функциями `mysql_*`

ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, перейди на [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). Вот [годная статья](http://dandreev.com/blog/php-pdo-kratkoe-rukovodstvo/) и вот [ещё одна](http://labdes.ru/php-pdo-mysql-examples). Потрать время, сделай свой **level up**